# Word doc vanished after closing

Tags: microsoft-word, file-recovery

A friend's Word document vanished after she closed MS Word and it is unclear to me how it could have vanished.

- The document still shows up under "recent documents", but it cannot be opened since the file does not exist.
- It cannot be found in the Finder (its a MacBook) either.
- Even with hidden files showing, I can only find a `~$*.docx` file that only contains some metadata.
- I also tried a file recovery tool (EaseUS), but it did not find any Word documents at all.
- Of course I also checked the Trash and Time Machine, but no luck there either.
- The usual AutoRecovery folder does not exist and it is not in the temporary files (the Macbook was restarted since).

What else could I try to recover the document?

Comment: Look to see whether Word offers to show "recovered" documents or "Recover Unsaved Documents" (at the bottom of the ''Open'' dialog).

Comment: Where were you saving this document before, Documents folder or other local drive? Are you saving the file in any cloud drive such as OneDrive, iCloud etc? Check if this article is helpful: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/how-recover-lost-deleted-items-mac-finder-sidebar